# Converting from ASP.NET MVC 2 to ASP.NET MVC 4 - why does my form report error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im converting a large MVC 2 application to MVC 4. I dont necessarily want to use Razor right now, i just want to migrate it and deal with the Razor subsequently. I can change this a bit of the time.

However, i have a problem with the forms:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 50px">    
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
    <div id="LoginContainer" style="margin: auto; width: 960px;">
        <div style="margin: auto; width: 400px">
            <img src="/Content/Images/logo.png" width="400" alt=""
                style="margin-top: 50px; margin: auto" />
        </div>
        <table style="width: 310px; margin: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: small; color: #333333">
                        Username</div>
                    <input type="text" name="username" style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;
                        background-color: #ffffff; width: 300px;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: small; color: #333333">
                        Password</div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;
                        background-color: #ffffff; width: 300px;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.CheckBox("rememberMe")%>
                    <label style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: small" for="rememberMe" class="logintext">
                        Remember me?</label><br />
                    <input class="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Log On" style="padding: 5px; width: 100px;
                        background-image: url('/content/images/button_bg.png'); border: 1px solid gray;
                        color: White" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="LoginControl">
    </div>
    <div style="width:500px;margin:auto;color:#666;font-size:xx-small;text-align:center;font-family:verdana;margin-top:50px;">

    </div>    
    <%if (ViewData["LoginError"] != null)
      { %>
    <div id="LoginError" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")%>
    </div>
    <%}
       } %>
</body>
</html>
```

The Html.BeginForm(), and in fact all the controls, reports the following errors:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'ValidationSummary' and no extension method 'ValidationSummary' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBox' and no extension method 'CheckBox' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When i check out the "HTML" helper i dont see the methods i refer at all in the method list. What am I missing?

Comment: could you share the rest of your page? I think this happens because of an error further in the form definition, and MVC just links it to the BeginForm() method.

Comment: I pasted all the code, I copied the file from my MVC 2 project to my MVC 4 project. It is working in my MVC 2 project.

Comment: The usual reason for these types of issues is the Web.config file in the Views folder hasn't been updated to reference MVC version 4 instead of version 2, similar to [Upgrading 3 to 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806). Dunno what steps you're following but [this blog](http://blog.codelab.co.nz/2013/07/05/upgrading-mvc-project-2-to-4-and-open-it-in-vs-2012/) looks useful.

Comment: In regards to what i did to upgrade. I created a new MVC 4 project and copied all the files into that one - figured that would work...